# Find the confidence level used based on multiple intervals

Tags: hypothesis-testing, confidence-interval

I am given the following table of confidence levels for a $\mu$ of a $X\cap N(0,1)$.

[image]

and I'm asked to find the level of confidence used.
Initially I thought when I chose, for exemple, a 90% confidence level, 10% of my samples would't contain the parameter, but some excel simulation proved me wrong.

Given the table can we be sure of the confidence level used ?
And similarly, when testing hypothesis can we find the significance level used given the the number of false positives (knowing what the real parameter is).

Edit:
The exercise is the following: We got 20 samples (dimension not known) from a population with $N(0,1)$ distribution. Next we built a confidence interval (always using the same confidence level) for the average value of the population given the data we collected (the intervals displayed in the table).
The questions is: can we say what confidence level is used ? (one of the opinions is "we can't tell")

Excel simultation:
Using norm.inv(rand();0;1) I built 40 samples, each with dimension 56. Next I build the appropriate confidence interval ($\bar{X}-\frac{S \space t_{n-1}^{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\sqrt{n-1}}$, $\bar{X}+\frac{S \space t_{n-1}^{1-\frac{\alpha}{2}}}{\sqrt{n-1}}$).

For a 90% confidence level I get simulations where 9 of the 40 intervals don't contain 1. So it seems that the above problem can't have an definitive answer.

Using the above samples I tested $H_0: \mu = 1 \space vs \space H_1: \mu >1$, using the T statistics and a significant level of 0,1 (so out of the 40 I would only get 4 type I erros). I got on some simulations 8 type I errors.

Edit2:
I think that I know get it. In my simulation of confidence interval which one has a 10% probability of not containing the real parameter (in this case 1), but I in reality I can get the case where I get 8/40 intervals don't contain the real parameter since this has a $40 \choose 8$$0.1^{8} \space 0.9^{40-8}$ probability of occurrence.

Comment: Please explain what "$\mu$ of a $X \cap N(0,1)$" means.  And tell us what you *do* know about this situation: with the information you have given, the question is not answerable with much precision.  You might want to describe the simulation, too, because any accurate 90% confidence interval procedure will indeed cover the parameter close to 90% of the time.

Comment: I edited the post.